# Google Signin doesn't redirect after sign out

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign in on my website which until recently worked fine. Now when the user signs out, Google signs out, however doesn't redirect the user to the page that I set in the script.

I'm using following sign out script:

```
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
      window.location = "/user/logout"
    });
  }
</script>
```

The console log is executed, but the the window.location should redirect the user, which it doesn't. No errors, just nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

I can actually see the url /user/logout being called in the backend, but it doesn't do anything in the user's browser. Below the python code that runs when the url is loaded. The session is not unset either, cause when I hit refresh the user is still signed in on my app (but not on Google).

```
class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.auth.unset_session()
    self.redirect(self.uri_for('home'))
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I open the link in a new tab, it signs out perfectly fine. If I change the target to '_top' or '_self', it just calls the url in the backend but doesn't execute in the browser for unknown reason.

**UPDATE 3**

Figured out the reason by: the browser (Chrome in this case) is cancelling the request. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by making a normal

```
<a href="/user/logout"></a>
```

and moving the Google signout script to the page that the user is redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to do the sign out after `GoogleAuth`(in your code `auth2`) is fully initialized. Check the official [Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenwzxhzdk60oninitwzxhzdk61_wzxhzdk62onfailurewzxhzdk63).

In your case try

```
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.then(function(){
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log('User signed out.');
          window.location = "/user/logout"
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't change anything unfortunately.